# IEnumerable Items Disappear - Exist in DAL but not Caller

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have a DAL method that retrieves items. The items exist in the DAL method, but not in the calling code. How is that possible?

**Calling code:**

```
IEnumerable<InstallationSummary> installationSummaryList =
InstallationSummaryLogic.GetByServerAppAndGroup(appServer, appWithValidGroup);
```

**DAL method showing that items indeed exist:**

[image]

**Calling code, showing no items. Where did they go?**
(This is the same line shown at the top of this question.)

[image]

**The only thing in between the DAL method and the calling code is a logic class that's simply a pass-through. For completeness, I've included it here:**

```
    public static IEnumerable<InstallationSummary> GetByServerAppAndGroup(ApplicationServer appServer, ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup appWithGroup)
    {
        return DataAccessFactory.GetDataInterface<IInstallationSummaryData>().GetByServerAppAndGroup(appServer, appWithGroup);
    }
```

**Edit - Show Entire DAL Method**

```
public IEnumerable<InstallationSummary> GetByServerAppAndGroup(ApplicationServer appServer, ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup appWithGroup)
{
    IQueryable<InstallationSummary> summaries = this.Database.InstallationSummaries
        .Include(x => x.ApplicationServer)
        .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.Application)
        .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroup)
        .Where(x => x.ApplicationServer.IdForEf == appServer.IdForEf)
        .Where(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.Application.IdForEf == appWithGroup.Application.IdForEf);

    if (appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroup == null)
    {
        return summaries.Where(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroup == null);
    }

    return summaries
        .Where(x =>
        x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup != null &&
        x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroup != null &&
        x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroup.IdForEf == appWithGroup.CustomVariableGroup.IdForEf);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GetByServerAppAndGroup` method filters `summaries` using a `Where` call (we can't see what it really is - it would be helpful if you'd cut and paste the method itself). My guess is that none of the results within `summaries` passes the filter in the `Where` call.

Comment: could it also be a problem with deferred execution? At what point in his code would we see the actual LINQ query executed? He might be thinking the DAL has the code because the debugger is enumerating the queries for him when he interrogates his collection.

Comment: @BradRem, if you expand Results View in the debugger, it should execute the query.

Comment: I added the DAL code to the question. However, if you'll notice in the screenshot, I already hit F10 on the return statement. Notice the ending method brace is highlighted. That means that the Where filter was already applied.

Comment: @BobHorn: But you're *displaying* the contents of `summaries`. The `Where` clause won't affect that - the *return value* of `Where` is filtered, but it doesn't change the *source* at all.

Comment: My bad. Let me capture that in an variable first, then return it. Then I can inspect to see if it was indeed the Where clause.

Comment: @JonSkeet: You were right. It was the Where clause. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BobHorn: No problem - glad it turned out to be simple :)